# Uplink port: standard LOCATION at beginning or end port?

Tags: switch, uplinks

Hopefully I don't get roasted for asking, but I DID google & search here for a bit without success. **What is the normal/industry-standard location to use as the uplink port(s) on a switch?** I imagine the end ports, but maybe its the beginning?

Goal: I want to follow industry standard practices & make it easier on another tech that may walk into my handy-work so they're not scratching their head

Comment: Just pick one or the other and be consistent.  There is no standard.

Comment: And document whatever you do - either with descriptions in the configuration, external documentation or (preferably) both.  If it's consistent and documented, you'll have done well by those who follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no industry standard. *Common practice* is to use either the first ports, or last ports. But it's a personal preference (or maybe company policy), one can use any port(s).

(If the switch has dedicated "uplink" ports, one would normally use those.)